# AWS Java SDK PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, certificate, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to debug an issue using Fiddler for which i need fiddler to capture my eclipse traffic.
I followed the steps as stated [here](https://westerndevs.com/capture-https-traffic-in-java-with-eclipse-and-fiddler/).

However, i am getting following exceptions as stated below:

```
**com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.
handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1136)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
     org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 43 more**
```

I also tried adding the FiddlerRootCertificate to the keystore, but it still threw this error.

What am i missing here?

FYI, i am writing a simple script that downloads object from S3 bucket.

Comment: u need to copy the .jts certificate to you jre/lib/security

Comment: How do i get the .jts certificate?

Comment: ok, i didn't read your line that you have added the certificate, so basically the error is due to the certificate issue only, your application that requires jre to launch expects a certificate as it requires you to authenticate which should be copied in a path /jre/lib/security , in my case i use .jts it might vary for you.
FiddlerRootCertificate - might not be the right one or your certificate name should match the host name of the machine

Comment: i went though the link you have mentioned and the steps are fine. Did you follow step 14 correct? i find the issue somewhere in step 10 to 14

Comment: I have made sure that i have added the certificate in  jre/lib/security and also as you pointed out, i rechecked to follow the steps as mentioned in the link but i'm getting the same error again.

Comment: i am sorry i cannot give the solution but the exact cause for this behavior is the certificate issue,

Comment: Thank you pointing out. I'll look for other certificates issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error either you have invalid access and secret key pair Or you are blocked out from accessing AWS servers from your network